# How to access mysql using javascript?

Tags: javascript, mysql

I know that most people say, "OH! It's not possible, use php" or whatever...
That would be a waste of my time. I don't want to hear that it's not possible.

I'm looking for anyway possible that I can access mysql using javascript. I don't care how much of a drawn out process it is or that it would take node.js.

Just give me a way to do it. Node.js or AJAX is something I'm willing to look into, but I'd rather just use javascript and nothing else.

I do know PHP, Node.js, and AJAX, so I'm not looking for an easy way out. I just want to find out how.

*** edit ***

I guess this would be more of what I am looking for:

Is there any other types of sql or some sort of database that is accessable by in browser javascript?

Comment: Disregarding the many other comments this post begs,  you do know that Node.js and AJAX _are_ JavaScript...yes?

Comment: Does your Javascript environment have access to a TCP socket? Are you able to run your database server listening on a public network interface? (I'm trying to figure out if this is a really clever or a really ignorant question.)

Comment: Javascript has to run inside a *javascript engine*.  Node.js is such an engine.  A web browser is a different kind of javascript engine.  So when you say, "I'd rather just use javascript and nothing else", what exactly are you looking for?  Something that runs the browser?

Comment: _"I don't want to heard that it's not possible, but there must be a way."_ - wait, what? Are you trying to demonstrate a can-do attitude, or is this just another variation on "I deny your reality and substitute my own"?

Comment: Are you aware that if you would connect directly to the database from JS, the password would be visible to all users?

Comment: I am aware of that, but that's not the point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should checkout https://mongolab.com/home   They provide full access to a NoSQL database using JSON objects which are directly accessible with jQuery calls.  I saw these guys at a Hackathon and ended up winning a prize! They are cool and will probably give you direct help if you click the support link.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly possible.  Web Application servers best suit that role, e.g. PHP, Cold Fusion, RubyOnRails, java(JSP), .net(ASP), etc.
You use javascript to send a request that the application server than uses to access the mysql server and... usually server up some of the results in a web page :)

Answer (score 0):

To connect mysql using javascript, you can use the mysql package from npm.

`npm i mysql`

```js
import mysql from "mysql";

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "social_media",
});

connection.connect();

const getUserById = (id) => {
  connection.query(`SELECT * FROM users where id = ${id}`, function (err, results, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log("The solution is: ", results);
  });
};

getUserById(7);

connection.end();
```