# Javascript library for mysql interaction into the browser

Tags: javascript, mysql

I'm creating a client side application that will rely only on a remote mysql database, all the project use vuejs. Is there any js library that can work into the browser to save and retrive data on the remote mysql db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the simplest answer is "you should never do it".

Because do this on the "client side" is not secure, you will expose sensitive information about your database, and this is not okay.

[You can see here why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9767691/14097137)

However, if you really want to (just don't), [here is](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-live-client#principles-of-mysql-live), is really old but is because is not a good thing to do, but you can try.

Comment: I don't need to store anything on client side, I will have a remote mysql database. I need a way to talk with it using javascript, maybe you've misunderstand the question.

Comment: I understood you, just check the "here is" link, there's the lib to do this. But you have to expose information like user and password by example, this is the sensitive information that I was talking about.